# Set Default Database name for queries in TERADATA

Tags: java, database, database-schema, teradata

I have this query:

```
Connection conn = null;
stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute("SELECT * FROM school.users");
```

and I got results from that query. If I try to implement this following code in java to set a default database:

```
stmt.execute("database school");
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
```

I have this error:

```
Exception-> [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.17] [Error 3807] [SQLState 42S02] Object 'users' does not exist
```

Can You see what is Wrong?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: stmt.execute("database school"); doesn't look valid

Comment: What is returned when you submit "SELECT DATABASE;" instead of your query?

Comment: Actually It brings me School

Answer (score 1):

Add DATABASE param in the url and try. 
eg. `url="jdbc:teradata://exampleDns/DATABASE=school"`

I hope this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
try{


conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
    stmt = conn.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");


}
 catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();

finally{
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
```

}

Comment: If I try that I have the same error, that 'users' doesn't exist, because I have different databases in that url, It's necessary to add school.users, but I want a default database.

Comment: @PabloGlez Did you specify the proper DB_URL, USER and PASS? In the DB_URL you specify you database, then pass your username and Password.

Comment: Yes I did, I have a right connection, I even can bring rows, put specifying school.users

Comment: A simple Teradata DB_URL would look like this jdbc:teradata://ServerHost/database=MyDatabaseName

I assume "school" is the database name? Does your DB_URL look like:
jdbc:teradata://localhost/database=school

Comment: url:"jdbc:teradata://localhost//TMODE=TERA,CHARSET=UTF16/database=school"? I have it like this but I'm still having that problem

Comment: "jdbc:teradata://localhost/database=school,TMODE=TERA,CHARSET=UTF16"

Comment: bad news, I did it but I still have the exception that users doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

What if you use the executeUpdate "method" of the Statement?

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
stmt = conn.createStatement();

stmt.executeUpdate("database school");

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
```